# Porting init.d script to systemd

Tags: systemd, sysvinit

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON="/usr/local/bin/redis-server"
PIDFILE="/var/run/redis/redis_7128.pid"
RUNDIR="/var/run/redis"
REDIS_USER="redis"
DAEMON_ARGS="/etc/redis/redis_7128.conf"
REDISPORT="7128"

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting $DAEMON: "
        touch $PIDFILE
        chown redis:redis $PIDFILE
        chmod 755 $RUNDIR

        if [ -n "$ULIMIT" ]
        then
                ulimit -n $ULIMIT
        fi

        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $REDIS_USER:$REDIS_USER --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
        then
                echo "$NAME."
        else
                echo "failed"
        fi
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --retry forever/TERM/1 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
        then
                echo "$NAME."
        else
                echo "failed"
        fi
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        sleep 1
        ;;

  restart|force-reload)
        ${0} stop
        ${0} start
        ;;

  status)
        echo -n "$DESC is "
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --signal 0 --name ${NAME} --pidfile ${PIDFILE}
        then
                echo "running"
        else
                echo "not running"
                exit 1
        fi
        ;;

  *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I have the above script written for `init.d`, I want to port it to `systemd`.

I tried writing my own, and saved it at `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` but the variables are not expanding

```
[Unit]
Description=My Redis Service

[Service]
Type=forking
#User=redis
Restart=on-failure
RemainAfterExit=yes
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/system/redisenv
ExecStart=start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $REDIS_USER:$REDIS_USER --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
ExecStart=echo -n "Starting $DAEMON: "
ExecStart=touch $PIDFILE
ExecStart=chown redis:redis $PIDFILE
ExecStart=chmod 755 $RUNDIR
ExecStart=if [ -n "$ULIMIT" ];then ulimit -n $ULIMIT ;fi  
ExecStart=if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $REDIS_USER:$REDIS_USER --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS ;then echo "$NAME." ; else echo "failed"; fi  

ExecStop=start-stop-daemon --stop --retry forever/TERM/1 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the `EnvironmentFile` that I wrote for it while porting, I saved it at `/etc/systemd/system/redisenv`

```
SECRET=pGNqduRFkB4K9C2vijOmUDa2kPtUhArN
ANOTHER_SECRET=JP8YLOc2bsNlrGuD6LVTq7L36obpjzxd
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/redis-server
PIDFILE=/var/run/redis/redis_6382.pid
RUNDIR=/var/run/redis
REDIS_USER=redis
DAEMON_ARGS=/etc/redis/redis_6382.conf
REDISPORT=6382
```

After that I did

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/systemd/system/redis.service
sudo chmod 777 /etc/systemd/system/redisenv
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start redis-service
```

but it returns

> ```
> Failed to start redis.service: Unit redis.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument. 
> See system logs and 'systemctl status redis.service' for details.
> ```

and `sudo systemctl status redis.service` returns

> ```
> ● redis.service - My Redis Service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
>    Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
>    Active: inactive (dead)
>
> Aug 14 19:11:31 squid2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redis.service:16] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $REDIS_USER:$REDIS_USER --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS ;then echo "$NAME." ; 
> Aug 14 19:11:31 squid2 systemd[1]: redis.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
> Aug 14 19:11:37 squid2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redis.service:10] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $REDIS_USER:$REDIS_USER --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
> Aug 14 19:11:37 squid2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redis.service:11] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: echo -n "Starting $DAEMON: "
> Aug 14 19:11:37 squid2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redis.service:12] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: touch $PIDFILE
> Aug 14 19:11:37 squid2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redis.service:13] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: chown redis:redis $PIDFILE
> Aug 14 19:11:37 squid2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redis.service:14] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: chmod 755 $RUNDIR
> Aug 14 19:11:37 squid2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redis.service:15] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: if [ -n "$ULIMIT" ];then ulimit -n $ULIMIT ;fi
> Aug 14 19:11:37 squid2 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/redis.service:16] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $REDIS_USER:$REDIS_USER --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS ;then echo "$NAME." ; 
> Aug 14 19:11:37 squid2 systemd[1]: redis.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
> ```

Any help in porting the `init.d` script to `systemd` ??

The first that problem that I can see is that the script the variables are not variable expansion is not occuring

Comment: The chmod 777 /etc/systemd/system/* is a very bad idea. The ExecStart is not for shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Unix StackExchange.

I recommend starting with one of the systemd unit files for Redis that have have already been [created and shared](https://gist.github.com/mkocikowski/aeca878d58d313e902bb)?

The attempt at a direct translation is making it harder than it needs to be because systemd has built-in support for many of the features which were coded in bash before:

- `User=` directive sets the user that it runs as
- `start-stop-daemon` is not needed
- Explicit Pidfile management is not needed.
- `systemd` already sets a sane PATH variable, so you don't need to.
- `systemd` has a lot of options to control resources, so calling ulimit is not needed. See `man systemd.resource-control` for all your options.

For all those reasons, the example `redis.service` files you'll find online on are rather short.

Systemd supports environment variable substitution only in limited cases. `man systemd.service` covers the details when you search for "environment variable substition" in the docs.

Comment: Why don't we need `start-stop-daemon`? Does systemd automatically detect if a daemon is running or not and gives error if it's already running?

Comment: As the linked article indicates, systemd doesn't need the program to daemonize as it takes care of all that itself (using a cgroup container), so it can actually do a better job of tracking the program if you *don't* daemonize it! The only time that you need to use `Type=forking` is if the server handles requests by forking, like Samba does.

Comment: @JohnDickery Managing daemons is one of the major features of `systemd`. So yes, it tracks the status of what's running and offers a `status` command to check the status of any running command.